# Set default value on SELECT using two way data binding of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Scenario: I need to display a list of data in SELECT tag using AngularJS. Since AngularJS allows two way data binding, I want it to behave as it without extra effort. Here is the approach that I did.

```
Model
 public class Department
    {
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }

Query to get the data

 Departments = user.Departments.Select(x=> new Department {DepartmentId= x.UserID,DepartmentName= x.FirstName}).OrderByDescending(x=>x.DepartmentName)
```

Assign data to $scope

```
 $scope.loadData = function () {
                $http.get(baseurl.resolve("~/api/users/getbyid?userId=" + userId)).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.DepartmentID = data.DepartmentID;
                    $scope.profile = data;
                });
            };
```

Event when value is change in SELECT

```
   $scope.selectDepartment = function (selectedDepartment) {
        $scope.profile.DepartmentID = selectedDepartment;
    };
```

Binding data to UI

```
          <select data-ng-model="DepartmentID" data-ng-selected="0" data-ng-change="selectDepartment(DepartmentID)" data-ng-options="department.DepartmentId as department.DepartmentName for department in profile.Departments">
```

This seems not a vanilla approach, I need to set this one `$scope.profile.DepartmentID = selectedDepartment;` for me to get the selected value. Is there a proper approach just to update the value in another way around?

Comment: You could use `ng-init` in your `<select>` tag, but initializing the model in the controller like you did is considered best practice afaik.

Comment: Your right, how about this one  $scope.selectDepartment = function (selectedDepartment) {
        $scope.profile.DepartmentID = selectedDepartment;
    }; ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$scope.selectDepartment = function (selectedDepartment) 
{
        $scope.DepartmentID = selectedDepartment;
};
```

Remove ng-change from so now it is

```
<select data-ng-model="DepartmentID" data-ng-selected="0" data-ng-options="department.DepartmentId as department.DepartmentName for department in profile.Departments">
```

Comment: I did that here  $scope.loadData. Please see the code

Comment: Hmmmm, that is the code that I need to remove. I want  a plain approach without using that code. Since AngularJs is a two way binding, I thought that the $scope.DepartmentID is automatically updated.

Comment: When selected index change why you are call function for select item?

Comment: I call it since the value is not automatically updated. I need to remove this code $scope.selectDepartment = function (selectedDepartment) {
        $scope.profile.DepartmentID = selectedDepartment;
    }; along the selected change event. This one data-ng-change="selectDepartment(DepartmentID)"

Comment: just remove ng-change from select.so what issue now?

Comment: Please provide plunker for same

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/LrhAQ/856/. How can get the selected value without the change event code?

Comment: In html you can get but for that you must one function for that man

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to put selected DepartmentId from dropdown to a variable called $scope.profile.DepartmentID.

In this case, you need to put ng-model = "profile.DepartmentID" for SELECT element

Check with something like ng-bind="profile.DepartmentID" to some element.
Here you can see updated DepartmentID.